# Find all possible sums of the combinations of integers from a set, efficiently

Tags: python, algorithm, math, optimization

Given an integer n, and an array a of x random positive integers, I would like to find all possible sums of the combinations with replacement (n out of x) that can be drawn from this array.

For example:

```
n = 2, a = [2, 3, 4, 6]
all combinations = [2+2, 2+3, 2+4, 2+6, 3+3, 3+4, 3+6, 4+4, 4+6, 6+6]
all unique sums of these combination = {4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 12}
```

This can of course easily be solved by enumerating and summing all possible combinations, for example in Python:

```
from itertools import combinations_with_replacement

n = 2
a = [2,3,4,6]

{sum(comb) for comb in combinations_with_replacement(a, n)}
```

Is there a more efficient way to do this? I have to do this for n up to 4 and a up to a 1000 values, which gives 4e10 combinations, while the number of unique sums will be several orders of magnitude less for arrays with integers whose values aren't too far apart, so I would guess there must be a more efficient way.

For example when n=3 and a is the set of the first 1000 even numbers, there will be only 2998 unique sums out of 1.6E8 possible combinations.

** Original question was updated to state that integers are only positive

Comment: You say "first" 1000 even numbers, so you're not really talking about all integers but only about positive or non-negative integers, right? Please say that then.

Comment: And you say *"values aren't too far apart"*. How far apart are they?

Comment: "For example when n=3 and a is the set of the first 1000 even numbers, there will be only 2998 unique sums out of 1.6E8 possible combinations" - sure. And if `a` is the set of the first 1000 powers of 4, every sum will be distinct.

Comment: Also, what's a realistic n for you? For large n I have yet another idea.

Comment: @KellyBundy Amazing! The underlying problem is chemistry based, I don't think I'll ever need more than n=4

Comment: And what about how far apart they are? Or better: How many numbers do you have, and what's that largest number? That determines how efficient each solution is, so I can't write a realistic benchmark if I don't know what's a realistic input.

Comment: @KellyBundy let's say that the first thousand positive even numbers is realistic. Though there will be some uneven mixed in as well

Comment: Ok I added that as benchmark now. That's a pretty special case, I imagine a solution specially targeting such input could be even faster. But my bitset solutions are already doing fairly well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
sums = {0}
for _ in range(n):
    sums = {s + x for s in sums for x in a}
```

Or using a bitset (assumes your numbers are non-negative):

```
sums = 1
for _ in range(n):
    new = 0
    for x in a:
        new |= sums << x
    sums = new
sums = {i for i, bit in enumerate(reversed(bin(sums))) if bit == '1'}
```

Which one is faster depends on the density of your numbers.

A further optimization of the second solution which can also handle negative numbers (it translates all values so that the smallest becomes 0):

```
sums = 1
minimum = min(a)
b = [x - minimum for x in a]
for _ in range(n):
    new = 0
    for x in b:
        new |= sums << x
    sums = new
sums = {
    i + n*minimum
    for i, bit in enumerate(reversed(bin(sums)))
    if bit == '1'
}
```

Yet another, intended for dense sets:

```
minimum = min(a)
maximum = max(a)
sums = set(a) if n else {0}
for i in range(2, n + 1):
    new = set()
    for s in range(minimum * i, maximum * i + 1):
        for x in a:
            if s - x in sums:
                new.add(s)
                break
    sums = new
```

One for large n, working like exponentiation by squaring:

```
sums = {0}
while n:
    if n % 2:
        sums = {s + x for s in sums for x in a}
    n //= 2
    if n:
        a = {x + y for x in a for y in a}
```

Benchmark according to your *"let's say that the first thousand positive even numbers is realistic. Though there will be some uneven mixed in as well"* (I used "some"=42) and with n=4 (since you said *"I don't think I'll ever need more than n=4"*).

```
   2.14 ±  0.03 ms  Kelly2
   2.44 ±  0.04 ms  Kelly3
  45.10 ±  4.05 ms  Kelly4b
 208.19 ±  2.22 ms  Kelly4
 807.97 ±  4.79 ms  Kelly1
1216.60 ± 19.22 ms  Kelly5
```

Benchmark code ([Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=5Va9btswEJ7rpzigKCw5jiM5NloY8dSxY0fDMCjrlBCRKIGkErluHqNTlyzt3lfoY_RpeqQoS3acpD_oVC8yecfv7r7veNLnr8VGX-Xi_v5LqZPTNz9efIoxgXeYppvQY0MQ_qwH9FNlpmAO2-DOLpNcwgq4AMnEJXqNV9dTwQlU1lEZR7ttVpVZsRpGoi5lbev1doHHRwKHz4UVeEtuwW7dhmp9Gr-P8xr24gKqw7zJ3k1tyy0SH0LEtYFDUWYomUZP4g1KhbEXceGZ077vA0-s43wO_bB_1ynq_NGiMi54Vma0pn8e8-1mRMtFBac7a1vP8o-piP6Oip2dk7Ri4DLbC_OrPLVQXb7sbpe0SZe0ozxlrGo2WdVsuvwVatoxISidVOFe9_KWuzHFoIrCBxQaAH-vPtWeatIZmKKbNAaWmy7SU73oCFAkc9XckYceLp8Ri2NP-UfNkUR2_Yx89SV7CXmhecY_MM1zMQMtN2SJtGRrzcUl5HEMpFxEikHCpdIdMaJ_owYzxlxq6hDCv8bNPGVZFDOoZnDqVfAKxq5h_mPddipMn5jKt1c8RRCz7u0Shr_95H5nQtsi4OxsDuM91H1EI-G2IrhNB8D-3Tw27ZNSrE0W9atm6Ca_e56756R5Ru7PlA7KPDNSxvTgWUGNA4plRYq1RWnqbKU5gTtrhkwMaT_Gm9qF-h8bY4EyWa3zUmiUwJS1mVvyNpcS11qgUj1Th2gbKGzaxDauDe05yxDCYDCY-OZZK45VQTDkaOtdBMtavl07JwbX2lpGJaoytWc6zjagUkg5N_a5Qzf5vi8Q457J3kqbzGCxPAhwZ5vI8KO8xJWgjfdCU_-HeG797fB219HCLZKlv5hNl8uuhkl_a2j1tPJnr0fj5A6-f6OGMhzbvando37q93oHb6pw6mLTa0GY8CnJ5e1u9DgIiMbmxtM4UkdYJqfAOA1hMvYPh0iNe2LP1kZBxsmTlOuAXEy5nbnxqAwNLSNWFChqmjyfhoEOWqcYU4dQM5B0eLXB61Fn5XCEFJIL7TUCDSEZrVaCZbha-fXXmftIaz7WfgI)):

```py
def Kelly1(a, n):
    sums = {0}
    for _ in range(n):
        sums = {s + x for s in sums for x in a}
    return sums

def Kelly2(a, n):
    sums = 1
    for _ in range(n):
        new = 0
        for x in a:
            new |= sums << x
        sums = new
    return {i for i, bit in enumerate(reversed(bin(sums))) if bit == '1'}

def Kelly3(a, n):
    sums = 1
    minimum = min(a)
    b = [x - minimum for x in a]
    for _ in range(n):
        new = 0
        for x in b:
            new |= sums << x
        sums = new
    return {
        i + n*minimum
        for i, bit in enumerate(reversed(bin(sums)))
        if bit == '1'
    }

def Kelly4(a, n):
    minimum = min(a)
    maximum = max(a)
    sums = set(a) if n else {0}
    for i in range(2, n + 1):
        new = set()
        for s in range(minimum * i, maximum * i + 1):
            for x in a:
                if s - x in sums:
                    new.add(s)
                    break
        sums = new
    return sums

# optimization: try subtracting odd numbers first
def Kelly4b(a, n):
    minimum = min(a)
    maximum = max(a)
    sums = set(a) if n else {0}
    a = sorted(a, key=lambda x: -(x % 2))
    for i in range(2, n + 1):
        new = set()
        for s in range(minimum * i, maximum * i + 1):
            for x in a:
                if s - x in sums:
                    new.add(s)
                    break
        sums = new
    return sums

def Kelly5(a, n):
    sums = {0}
    while n:
        if n % 2:
            sums = {s + x for s in sums for x in a}
        n //= 2
        if n:
            a = {x + y for x in a for y in a}
    return sums

funcs = Kelly1, Kelly2, Kelly3, Kelly4, Kelly4b, Kelly5

from random import sample
from statistics import mean, stdev
from time import perf_counter as time

# Correctness
for n in range(11):
    a = sample(range(1, 10**4), 10)
    expect = funcs[0](a, n)
    for f in funcs:
        result = f(a, n)
        assert result == expect

# Speed
times = {f: [] for f in funcs}
def stats(f):
    ts = [t * 1e3 for t in sorted(times[f])[:5]]
    return f'{mean(ts):7.2f} ± {stdev(ts):5.2f} ms '

for _ in range(15):
    evens = list(range(2, 2001, 2))
    odds = sample(range(1, 2000, 2), 42)
    a = sorted(evens + odds)
    n = 4
    for f in funcs:
        t0 = time()
        result = f(a, n)
        times[f].append(time() - t0)
        del result

for f in sorted(funcs, key=stats):
    print(stats(f), f.__name__)
```

Comment: Does the second one make the extra assumption that all numbers are nonnegative?

Comment: @Stef Yes, based on that "first" in the question.

Comment: But the "first thousand even numbers" was just one example of array. If your first code doesn't need the assumption but your second code needs it, it's worth spelling out the assumption explicitly in your answer. Especially since the second code is much more complicated than the first.

Comment: @Stef If there are negatives, I could add the minim... wait a moment, thats also an optimization so let me do that real quick anyway.

Comment: @Stef It's only an example, but it demonstrates that they're not thinking about negative numbers and implies that there aren't any in general.

Comment: @Stef Alright, mentioned the assumption and added third solution.

Comment: @jonas87 I'm not really interested in non-public stuff. If I do something, I want more than one person to benefit from it. What's the follow-up? If it's minor, it might be ok to include it in the question. Otherwise, it might be better to ask as a new question.

Comment: @KellyBundy Ok np, it's slightly related but a different problem, I'll consider posting as a new question, thanks again! It's given the same n, list a and the sums that were found, then find for any one of the sums, one set of n integers from the list a that results in that sum

Comment: @jonas87 Ok, yeah, that's related but really different, so wouldn't be good to modify this question with that. All solutions would have to be changed, and I don't see a way to make the bitset solutions work for that.